# Why is the tritium nucleus smaller than the deuterium nucleus?

Tags: nuclear-physics, binding-energy, isotopes

The rms nuclear charge radius of deuterium is approximately $2.1\,\mathrm{fm}$, while the charge radius of tritium is given by $1.8\,\mathrm{fm}$ although there is an additional neutron. Similarily, the charge radius of the Helium-4 nucleus is smaller than for Helium-3.

Can this be explained by the increased binding energy due to completed nuclear shells or is there some other intuitive effect?

Comment: "Increased binding" is the key.